# How to persist a restored db in my container so that it can be reused

Tags: mongodb, docker, mongodump, mongorestore

When building a docker image, I'm dumping an external db on a directory inside my container using mongodump, then I start a mongodb and execute a restore (mongorestore). Everything  seems to works fine when seeing the log. My goal is to deliver docker image containging data in the database, that could be launched with prepopulated data. This way my end user can "play" with it along with a web app. Notice that I am wondering if the web app could update this data .. Losing the data after the container is stopped is not a problem in my use case.

Here the complete dockerfile

FROM mongo

```
RUN mongodump --verbose --uri="mongodb://....."  --out=./izidump2

RUN mongod --fork --dbpath /data/db --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log;  \
     mongorestore --uri="mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb" --verbose ./izidump2;  \
     mongo --eval "db.createUser({ user: 'root', pwd: 'root', roles: ['readWrite', 'dbAdmin'] })" mydb;
```

Unfortunately when running the container the db does not exist..
When connecting to an instance of the running container and go to /data/db , the directory is empty . Very strange since i have restored the data inside this directory and i did not get any complaint while running the mongo restore.

What did I miss ?

Comment: Hi Chab, have you read about [Docker Volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)? Can you edit your question and post your Dockerfile completely?

Comment: I finally ended up with the following : RUN mongodump --verbose --uri="mongodb://..."  --out=./izidump2
COPY docker/services/mongo-seed/init.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d and i put the mongorestore in the .sh file